# How to make InfoButton Bordered

Tags: iphone

How to make infobutton bordered?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(infoPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I have tried

```
infoItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

as well as

```
button.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

But none of them is working. Will appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIButtonTypeInfoLight` does not have a bordered version, you will have to create your own images to get a bordered Info type button.

Example:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:@"info.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] // where info.png is your custom image
```